# Very slow performance when updating records

Tags: c#, performance, postgresql

I am writing my C# application that connects to database, does couple selects and then inserts record back to the server in the network.

But I have around 40k records and my program processes one records like for 1 second.

I don't know how to improve the performance. Here are my sql getter and inserter. Any suggestions?

```
    public bool insert_and_ConfirmSQL(String Query, String comments)
    {
        bool success = false;
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        NpgsqlConnection mycon = new NpgsqlConnection();
        string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", tbHost, tbPort, tbUser, tbPass, tbDataBaseName);
        mycon.ConnectionString = connstring;
        cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = Query;
        mycon.Open();

        int temp = 0;
        try
        {
            temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            success = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            success = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mycon.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                mycon.Close();
            }
        }
        return success;
    }


    public String getString(String sql, NpgsqlConnection conn)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                    //  check count of Rows 
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        object o = dt.Rows[0][0];
                        if (o != DBNull.Value && o != null)
                        {
                            return o.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Return default value 
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Have you profiled the DB to see if that might be the issue?

Comment: Try executing those queries directly on the database, using something like the SQL Management Studio. If those are slow too, then you know the problem is on the DB side. Though 1 second is excessive even for a full table scan with 40k rows.

Comment: @romkyns - 40,000 rows isn't anything to a typical database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can improve performance by using a sql Datareader instead of DataSets.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.100).aspx#Y0

You then can Inspect the data while you are reading it from the database.

So I'd implement the above code with a DataReader and retime it.

Edit: Especially that getString method. if that ds.Fill was taking 40k rows that could be the cause of your performance problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no chance to help you with your sql statements because we don't know them.

The only (guessing) visible problem is that you are trying to loop for 40K records (you know how) with a new connection each time. Both routines provided as your code do exactly this. So do you need 40K calls to insert_and_ConfirmSQL and/or another 40K to getString routines?

If you really loop then update your code to use only one connection without closing it; the same can be done with a dataset (you have to clear it before use: ds.Clear()).

Needless to say that if your queries are huge (in terms of data), and/or indexes do not cover the queries, then delays are expected.

Try with this approach and let us know.